# What tense should be used when looking at an old photo?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, tenses

Commenting on a photo which was taken a few years back:

Question:

> Is this you?

Should I reply:

> Yes, this **is** a few years back.

or:

> Yes, this **was** a few years back.

Which of the above is correct: *is* or *was*?

Comment: As an English learner, you might find our sister site at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) a better fit for you.

Comment: All of them are correct, and all are used. One has a choice of past or present when dealing with images.

Answer (score 2):

All of them are correct, and all are used. One has a choice of past or present when dealing with images.

Comment: I have already read this somewhere.

Comment: @The, yes. I too.

Answer (score 1):

While making reference to the whole photo (which is always going to be taken in the past), I'd rather say:

> That was me in school,
>      That was me playing soccer,
>       That was me sucking my thumb,
>       That was John running after Sandra
>       That was me in my last church service

But if I'm spotting myself in the picture amongst other people, I'd say:

> This is me, this is John, and we were all with Sandra at her party
>       This is Mark, Matthew and I. We attended the same church service that day.
>       This is Andrew and that's me with the bowl hat. It was fun visiting grandma.

At least, it makes sense to me this way.

Answer (score -1):

> - Yes, this is, a few years back.
> - Yes, this is me a few years back.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the quesiton.